# Obfuscar - skip obfuscation of anonymous types

Tags: c#, obfuscation, anonymous-types, obfuscar

I'm using the open source obfuscation software "Obfuscar". Is there a way to configure it to not obfuscate the property names in my anonymous types?

I'm using RestSharp to send HTTP requests, and my Json body content is an anonymous type.

```
request.AddJsonBody(new {
    data = new {
        type = "attachments",
        attributes = new {
            name = "foo"
        }
    }
});
```

I would like it to NOT rename those properties like "data", "type" etc in the anonymous type, because renaming them affects the Json string that it gets serialized to.

Comment: Looks like it is a supported product, try emailing support@lextudio.com. https://support.lextudio.com/services/training.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In github obfuscar issues i found [this answer](https://github.com/obfuscar/obfuscar/issues/154#issuecomment-968096846) and it worked for me

You need to create the  node in Obfuscar xml configuration file:

`<SkipType name="*AnonymousType*" skipProperties="true" skipMethods="true" skipFields="true" skipEvents="true" skipStringHiding="true" />`

Example of full xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Obfuscator>
  <Var name="OutPath" value="C:\TMP" />
  <AssemblySearchPath path="C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\MyProject\bin\Release\net6.0" />
  <AssemblySearchPath path="C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.0" />
  <Module file="C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\MyProject\bin\Release\net6.0\MyProject.dll">
    <SkipType name="*AnonymousType*" skipProperties="true" skipMethods="true" skipFields="true" skipEvents="true" />
  </Module>
  <Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="false" />
  <Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />
</Obfuscator>
```

Next, you need to start obfuscar.exe -s "path_to_xml_configuration_file"

Also see the section in the Obfuscar documentation

https://docs.obfuscar.com/getting-started/configuration#exclusion-rules-by-configuration